# Server turn off without any log

Tags: server, crash

Our office have a server with 3 3090 GPUs.

And in feb, we bought one 3090 with different vendor from previous one and put it into our server.

Server spec

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04
- Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-148-generic
- Docker: 23.0.5
- NVIDIA Driver: 525.105.17
- CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper PRO 3955WX 16-Cores
- Mainboard: MC62-G40-00

It was fine until we ran some pytorch training script in docker(pytorch/pytorch:latest).

When I ran pytorch training script with "torchrun --nproc_per_node 4 run.py"

After 3 hours of heavy loads, computer suddenly turn off and it doesnt turn on even I pressed the power button.

Only way to turn on the server is plug out all electric wires connected to PSUs and plug in it again.

I tried few more times with the server to find some crashlog, but there is no crash logs in dmesg or journalctl or kern.log.

In IPMI log, I found this logs.

```
 10f | 05/11/2023 | 17:11:15 | System Event | OEM System boot event | Asserted
 110 | 05/11/2023 | 17:11:22 | System Event | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 111 | 05/11/2023 | 17:11:22 | System Event #0xff | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 112 | 05/11/2023 | 22:43:56 | System Event #0xff | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 113 | 05/11/2023 | 22:43:56 | System Event | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 114 | 05/11/2023 | 22:44:49 | OS Boot #0x22 | boot completed - device not specified | Asserted
 115 | 05/11/2023 | 22:44:56 | Processor #0xe4 | Presence detected | Asserted
 116 | 05/11/2023 | 22:45:11 | Power Supply #0xe6 | Presence detected | Asserted
 117 | 05/11/2023 | 22:45:11 | Power Supply #0xe7 | Presence detected | Asserted
 118 | 05/12/2023 | 03:55:50 | Power Unit #0xff | Power off/down | Asserted
 119 | 05/12/2023 | 03:56:57 | System Event | OEM System boot event | Asserted
 11a | 05/12/2023 | 03:57:04 | System Event | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 11b | 05/12/2023 | 03:57:04 | System Event #0xff | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 11c | 05/12/2023 | 04:11:08 | System Event #0xff | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 11d | 05/12/2023 | 04:11:08 | System Event | Timestamp Clock Sync | Asserted
 11e | 05/12/2023 | 04:12:01 | OS Boot #0x22 | boot completed - device not specified | Asserted
 11f | 05/12/2023 | 04:12:08 | Processor #0xe4 | Presence detected | Asserted
 120 | 05/12/2023 | 04:12:23 | Power Supply #0xe6 | Presence detected | Asserted
 121 | 05/12/2023 | 04:12:23 | Power Supply #0xe7 | Presence detected | Asserted
```

118 says that power off asserted but I don't know where does it came from.
(By the way IPMI is come with GIGABYTE Mainboard)

Can you guess what could be problem?
Or could you give me some suggestion for futher analysis?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

install lm-sensor to monitor and log the heat, and power supply performance.

Comment: I'm watching sensors but It just give me temperature of PCI adaptor. However, ipmitool sensor list give me the temperature of CPU, GPU, PSU and it ranged from 78, 60, 49 for each. Does it critical temperature for all?

Comment: Well, its all relative... CPU temperature depends on the task size. However i think its a hardware failure... or problem in the power supply itself.